# Android subtle timing issue related to async callback seeing different results when debugging versus running

Tags: java, android

I have some code which has an async call (let's call it AsyncCallX) that takes a while to return a value (valA). This async call is called when login is successful. The successful login takes the user to another activity which wants to use the value valA.

However, when I use the debugger and set break points, the process works so that I am able to get the value valA whereas when I run without break points, I don't.

Comment: My guess is you are not waiting for your AsyncCall to complete and return results. So without the results the condition to take to next activity is not satisfied and it does not go to next screen. In case of break points, you are stopping the thread till you have the result and then the condition is satisfied. This is just a guess. There are infinite other reasons why this can be happening. Without any code to refer its impossible to know. So please always paste some code. No one can help you if you don't paste any code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is it true that the Android debugger pauses only Java threads and does not pause native and posix threads with the result that there may be data that returns from a native thread well in time when debugger is running whereas the data does not return from native thread in time when debugger is not running?